# Custom UITableViewCells Alloc Problrm

Tags: uitableview

So I have custom `UITableViewCells` (made with storyboard), and when I do not literally alloc, init the cells, the app crashes.  However, since they are custom cells, I don't know how to alloc/init them.

This code crashes:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    TableViewCells *cell = (TableViewCells *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCellsID"];

return cell;
}
```

with this printed to the console:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

I understand this means its crashing because there is no cell allocated yet, however when I try to allocate it, I have to specify a cell style.

So, when I build the cell as follows, it doesn't crash:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

     TableViewCells *cell = (TableViewCells *)[tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCellsID"];
     if (cell == nil)
          cell = [[TableViewCells alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"TableViewCellsID"];

     return cell;
}
```

The problem is the code that works (the second set), requires me to set a `UITableViewStyle`.  And as far as I know, there is no UITableViewStyleCustom.

Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It crashes in first case because there is no cell to reuse, and you are calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

EDIT - 
For custom cell initialisation you can check following threads -

[How to make custom TableViewCell with initWithStyle after 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754036/how-to-make-custom-tableviewcell-with-initwithstyle-after-3-0)

[initWithFrame vs initWithStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380710/initwithframe-vs-initwithstyle)

Comment: I understand why its crashing, but I need a way to create a cell, without specifying a style

Comment: why down vote? the problem which is mentioned in the code is crash, i provided the reason.Now for the second query i will give the answer.

Comment: If you interested in custom cell alloc, then you can check this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754036/how-to-make-custom-tableviewcell-with-initwithstyle-after-3-0

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380710/initwithframe-vs-initwithstyle